# fancontrol(1) and ipmi

Tags: fan, ipmi

My server supports IPMI, so I can run a script like this:

```
fanspeed() {
    # 0 C => 10, 55 C => 10, 65 C => 100
    sensors -j |
        jq '[.[]["temp1"]["temp1_input"]] |                                                   
              (max-55)*(100/(65-55)) |                                                        
               if . < 10 then 10 else if . > 100 then 100 else .|floor end end';
}

autofan() {
    setspeed() {
        ipmitool -I lanplus -H drac -U root -P password raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff $@
    }
    while true; do
        fanspeed=`fanspeed`
        printf "$fanspeed "$(setspeed $fanspeed)
        sleep 1
    done
}
```

This keeps the CPU temp < 65 C by increasing the fanspeed when the CPU temp > 55 C.

But this sounds like a job for `fancontrol`. Can `fancontrol` use IPMI to control the fan?

Answer (score 0):

My ash script in crontab every min is like: (TODO log somewhere)

```bash
#!/bin/ash
t='ipmitool  -I lanplus -H drac -U root -P password '
f=' raw 0x30 0x30 0x02 0xff '
$t  raw 0x30 0x30 0x01 0x00 # stop auto fan
TEMP=$(${t} sdr type temperature |tee /dev/tty |awk '{print $(NF-2)}' |sort -n |tail -1)
echo max TEMP=$TEMP
[ $TEMP -gt 65 ] && $t $f 0x2a || ( [ $TEMP -gt 55 ] && $t $f 0x1f ) || $t $f 0x0f
```

i.e. over 65 set fan 0x2a, over 55 set fan 0x1f, else 0x0f